# Override ASP.NET Nested Configuration Using Environment Variable

Tags: asp.net, powershell, asp.net-core

If a configuration file has a nested structure in it, what naming convention or variable name format is used to override that value in a command line environment like Powershell?

.NET config.json file:

```
{
    "L1a": {
        "L1a2a": {
            "L1a2a1": "value"
        },
        "L2b": false
    },
    "L1b": false
}
```

From the .NET application code, the configuration values can be accessed like this:

```
configObject["L1a:L1a2a:L1a2a1"];
configObject["L1a:L2b"];
configObject["L1b"];
```

Overriding a top level value using an environment variable is easy - just use the same key name:

```
$env:L1b = "true"
```

How can I set environment variables in Powershell to override the nested configuration file values?

`L1a:L1a2a:L1a2a1` and `L1a-L2b` are not valid environment variable names.
Using underscore like `L1a_L2b` does not work.

Comment: I think the answer might require using a hash table or dictionary object like `@{ key = value }`, but I can't get that to work either.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how this all is related. You have a .NET application that reads a JSON config file. Where exactly do PowerShell and environment variables come into play here? Does the application expose the configuration as environment variables?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it all has to do with the ASP.NET 5 configuration framework. http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define/access environment variables with colons (or other special characters) in their names by enclosing the variable name in curly brackets:

```psh
${env:L1a:L1a2a:L1a2a1} = 'othervalue'
```

Comment: I'm asking specifically about overriding ASP.NET 5 configuration settings. I either don't understand your answer, or think you've missed the point.

Comment: I just tried the curly braces to escape the variable name, and that worked. Thanks! The rest of the answer isn't really relevant. Sorry for the confusion around ASP.NET 5.

Comment: How do you save nested config data into an environment variable? I have '__' but didn't worked

Answer (score 5):

You should use `__` as seperator for your environment variable hierarchie see [aspnetcore-6.0#environment-variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#environment-variables) because it is platform agnostic (also applies to .net 5). This is the platform agnostic way of `asp .net` (will work in docker, linux and linux ...)

`${env__L1a__L1a2a__L1a2a1} = 'othervalue'`

Comment: Definitely use `__` to avoid platform-specific issues